# Expanding a lambda for each parameter of a parameter pack: Clang vs. GCC

Tags: c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

This code works fine in Clang 3.5:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void callFuncs() {}

template<typename Func, typename ...Funcs>
void callFuncs(const Func &func, const Funcs &...funcs)
{
    func();
    callFuncs(funcs...);
}

template<typename ...Types>
void callPrintFuncs()
{
    callFuncs(([] { std::cout << Types() << std::endl; })...);
}

int main()
{
    callPrintFuncs<int, float, double, std::string>();
}
```

However, in GCC 4.9, I get the following error instead:

```
test.cpp: In lambda function:
test.cpp:16:54: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':
     callFuncs(([] { std::cout << Types() << std::endl; })...);
                                                      ^
test.cpp:16:54: note:         'Types'
test.cpp: In function 'void callPrintFuncs()':
test.cpp:16:58: error: expansion pattern '<lambda>' contains no argument packs
     callFuncs(([] { std::cout << Types() << std::endl; })...);
```

So, which compiler has a bug, Clang or GCC? The Clang behavior makes the most sense to me at least.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47226 ?

Comment: Weird that this hasn't been fixed yet. I wanted to reconfirm it but when trying to create an account, it says that account creation is restricted... Is GCC dead?

Comment: Gcc, like many, is a victim of spammers. The page you were on gives instructions on how to create an account (send an email to overseers@...).

Comment: It appears, at first glance, that the code assumes an unexpanded parameter pack at the end of a statement is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc is broken here.  There are rules against unexpanded parameter packs in the standard, but the above parameter pack is expanded.

It is expanded *after the end of innermost statement it is in*, but the standard does not require that the parameter packs be expanded by the end of every statement.

The fact that gcc got it wrong is sort of understandable; naively, you'd think that a parameter pack can only be within one statement, and the failure to expand at the end of the statement is fatal.  But lambdas let you nest statements within statements.

A general workaround can be to pass in one lambda and pass in a "tag" type to it.

```
template<class T>struct tag_t{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<typename Func, typename ...Ts>
void callOnEachOf(Func&&func, Ts&&...ts)
{
  using discard=int[];
  (void)discard{0,((void)(
    func(std::forward<Ts>(ts))
  ),0)...};
}
template<typename ...Types>
void callPrintFuncs()
{
  callOnEachOf(
    [](auto tag){
      using Type=type_t<decltype(tag)>;
      std::cout << Type() << std::endl;
    },
    tag_t<Types>...
  );
}
```